# How to list non-empty subdirectories on linux?

Tags: bash, unix, directory

I have a directory containing multiple subdirectories. I want to list only those subdirectories that contain at least one file. How can I do that?

Comment: Did you want only directories that are immediate subdirectories of your directory, or *all* subdirectories no matter how deeply nested?

Comment: if a subdirectory contains other sub-sub directories but no files, I do not want it listed

Answer (score 86, accepted):

```
 find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -not -empty -type d
```

will give you all nonempty directories. If you want to exclude directories that contain only other directories (but no files), one of the other answers might be better...

Comment: The -mindepth and -maxdepth options restrict this to only the immediate subdirectories.  Adjust these to affect at which level results are returned.  Leaving them off will find all subdirectories at any level.

Comment: and remember that -not is GNU-stuff.  To be portable, use ! instead of -not (really; I don't see why you wouldn't just always use ! instead of -not, seeing as -not gives you no advantage whatsoever)

Comment: Because ! looks like it should be a shell metacharacter and I can never remember whether I have to quote it or not ;-) but you are right about it being more portable.  (I guess since this answer was accepted, GNU-specific syntax works for the OP)

Answer (score 11):

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 dirname | sort -u
```

Comment: Slightly shorter syntax for the same thing: find . -type f -exec dirname {} \; | sort -u

Comment: Terribly sorry. An unmatched single quote caused early termination. Totally my fault.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
find /nominated/directory -type f |
sed 's%/[^/]*$%% |
sort -u
```

Find files - drop file name part - sort uniquely.

It won't list subdirectories that contain only other sub-sub-directories.