# How do I find every non-empty Junk folder on an IMAP server?

Tags: shell, find, imap

If my users are all under, say:

```
/imap/user1
/imap/user2
/imap/user3
```

How do I find all of the non-empty **.Junk/cur/** folders under **/imap** ?

There is this [How to list non-empty subdirectories on linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815668/how-to-list-non-empty-subdirectories-on-linux) but I only want the non-empty subdirectories named **cur** that are themselves under a directory **.Junk**

I'm basically trying to find all the email that a given set of users on a server are marking as Junk/Spam.

Comment: Hoping for something little more elegant than
 find . -mindepth 3 -not -empty -type d|grep Junk\/cur

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-path` option:

```
find /imap -type d -not -empty -path '*/.Junk/cur'
```